# Theorem to Prove $e$ is Irrational

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

There is a theorem in this textbook I am using and the theorem is the following:

> If $e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{x^{n}}{n!}+\cdots $, then the number $e$ is irrational.

Then the proof of this theorem goes on about proving that $e^{-1}$ is irrational.

I don't understand how the proof relates to the theorem. Is the theorem missing some information that lets me know that showing $e^{-1}$ is irrational is equivalent to showing $e$ is irrational?

Edit: Sorry about that, what I meant was I don't understand what the theorem is saying. I already understand the proof. :)

Comment: It should be pretty clear that inverse of irrational is irrational

Comment: So you are asking if from $e^{-1}$ is irrational it follows that $e$ is irrational?

Comment: Suppose that $e^{-1}$ is irrational but $e$ don't. So $e$ is rational, and exists $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $e=\frac{p}{q}$ (irreductible). So $e^{-1}=\frac{q}{p}\Rightarrow e^{-1}$ is rational

Comment: Suppose $e$ is rational. Then $e^{-1}$ is rational as $e \neq 0$. Contradiction with your fact. So $e$ cannot be rational.

Comment: @Quality Sorry about that, what I meant was I don't understand what the theorem is saying. I already understand the proof. :)

Comment: It still is not clear what you are asking even

Comment: @Quality What does it mean by "If $e^{x}=1+x+\cdots + \frac{x^{n}}{n!}+\cdots $, ..."? I don't understand this part of the theorem.

Comment: @numericalorange It is a bit awkward to premise a theorem on a common knowledge fact/definition. And I suppose if this definition was literally all you were going on, and you managed to show $e^{-1}\equiv \sum (-1)^n /n!$ is irrational, you would need to show $e\equiv e^1\equiv \sum 1/n!$ is indeed the reciprocal of $e^{-1}$ as notation suggests before using the simple argument to conclude $e$ is irrational. This middle step is likely assumed common knowledge though. Is this what you’re asking about? You are not being clear at all here.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, this is very hard to explain... The premise is saying if $e^{x}$ is equal to its Maclaurin series, then $e$ is irrational, and yet the proof does not show that $e^{x}$ is equal to that series, it is just showing that $e^{-1}$ is irrational, so the premise is very confusing to me? Did the theorem mean "If $e^{x}$ is irrational for some $x$, then $e$ is irrational"?

Comment: @numericalorange well if a theorem starts with “if _” you don’t have to prove _. It’s an assumption. And here this assumption always holds so we don’t need it anyway (which is why I said it was awkward.) I would write the theorem “e is irrational.” If you want more context on what they actually meant (I may be making some wrong guesses here) it would be good to show the proof in full. you understand that $e^x$ *is* equal to its macklaurin series (for all $x$), right?

Comment: @numericalorange Maybe they hadn’t proved that fact about $e^x$ yet and they do later. Or maybe they’re taking the fact as common knowledge and it’s just bad writing in attempt to emphasize that they will be using the fact in the proof.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for taking the time to reply and help me as much as you can. You're the most helpful answer! I apologize to everyone for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a number is irrational then its reciprocal is irrational. For if its reciprocal could be written $a/b$ then the number itself could be written $b/a.$

Comment: Sorry about that, what I meant was I don't understand what the theorem is saying. I already understand the proof. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reciprocal of a non-zero rational number is also rational.

They proved  $1/e$ is irrational then the conclusion is that $e$ is also irrational because otherwise its reciprocal $1/e$ would have been rational as well.

Comment: Sorry about that, what I meant was I don't understand what the theorem is saying. I already understand the proof. :)